# The "general uncertainty" of the harmonic oscillator defies the correspondence principle?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, semiclassical

If you use the definition of $(\Delta x)^2 = \langle n | x^2 | n \rangle - \langle n | x | n \rangle^2$ and the same for $(\Delta p)^2$ to calculate $\Delta x \Delta p$ for the state $|n\rangle$ of a harmonic oscillator, you'll get
$$\Delta x \Delta p=\frac{\hbar}{2}(2n+1)$$
This is actually problem 10 of the sixth chapter from the 3rd. edition of Gasiorowicz "Quantum Physics".

So, I'm interpreting this solution as a "general formula" to obtain the product of uncertainties for a given state of the harmonic oscillator. If $n=0$, we get exactly the minimum value of the uncertainty principle, correspondent to the ground state of the harmonic oscillator/gaussian wave packet. And we can see that, as $n$ grows, so does our product of uncertainties. In light of the correspondence principle, stating that as the quantum numbers become large we should start to see the classical limit emerge, how one should see this product of uncertainties getting bigger, putting us continuously at the quantum realm?

Comment: This formulation of the correspondence principle is somewhat off (and outdated ...). The correct way to generate classical behaviour in a quantum harmonic oscillator (or bosonic field theories) are coherent states.